# Using an external alias with primary account

Tags: gmail, google-apps-email, alias

Let's say I have a primary gmail account called john@gmail.com. I also have an university's email, called say john123456@university.com. And this university email has an alias, served by the university's server, called john@university.com.

**My question is**: how can I fully incorporate the university email alias to my primary email environment? In other words, I want to send, receive, and have people see ONLY the email alias, not the original one.

Right now I've added the account to my gmail page, so I can receive emails as the alias, "Send email as" the alias, but receivers still see the john123456@university.com, not john@university.com. I've tried many things already, read all support pages, but I've found nothing covering this situation.

**Edit**: This link from Google Support says it's impossible. But is it really?
"Messages you send will appear to be from the domain alias or email alias. The return-path of the message will indicate your primary mail addresses, but only recipients who look at the original message header will notice."

Comment: What do you mean "receivers still see the john123456@..."? When you "Send Mail As" john@, do the messages say something like "sent on behalf of..."?

Comment: There's no "sent on behalf of...", and what I mean is that recipients still see john123456@university.com besides my name, and not john@university.com.